# Sonarlint Violations for Guava Suppliers used with Memoize

Tags: java, java-8, guava, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am using Guava Suppliers to memoize and reload some data after fixed time some in my class. Recently sonarlint started generating warning with message such as 'Java 8 features should be preferred to Guava (squid:S4738)'.

Can anyone tell me i can actually use Java Supplier here in any way to achieve the same functionality?

Code Sample

```
private final Supplier<Set<Integer>> cache = Suppliers.memoizewithExpiration(fetchData(), 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `import java.util.function.Supplier` instead of `com.google.common.base.Supplier`.

Guava's `Supplier` extends Java's `Supplier` so it's safe to use.